# Error 1061 hittestobject in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, hittest

hey everyone im working on something but everytime when I test run I keep getting the following error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild. Deeltoets3.as   /Deeltoets3/src line 107    Flex Problem

1120: Access of undefined property blam.    Deeltoets3.as   /Deeltoets3/src line 105    Flex Problem

1120: Access of undefined property blam.    Deeltoets3.as   /Deeltoets3/src line 106    Flex Problem

1120: Access of undefined property blam.    Deeltoets3.as   /Deeltoets3/src line 107    Flex Problem

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestObject through a reference with static type Class. Deeltoets3.as   /Deeltoets3/src line 103    Flex Problem

this is the code, does anyone know what im doing wrong?
 thankss

```
package
{
    import figures.Blam;
    import figures.Muur;
    import figures.Sun;
    import figures.Vogel;

    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;




    public class Deeltoets3 extends Sprite
    {
        // Een afbeelding toevoegen 
        [Embed(source="fotos/sky.jpg")] 
        private var BackgroundPicture:Class; 
        private var background:Bitmap; 

        //maakt een variabele aan voor de vogel
        public var calimeroDeVogel:Vogel;

        //maakt een variabele aan voor de zon
        public var movingSun:Sun;

        //maakt een variabele aan voor de zon
        public var Gebouw:Muur;

        //maakt een variabele aan voor de crash
        public var blam:Blam;

        // maakt een variabele aan voor het achtergrond geluid
        public var achtergrondMuziek:Sound; 



        // Constructor functie
        public function Deeltoets3()
        {
            // De stage instelllen op niet meeschalen
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            // Toevoeging van het achtergondplaatje op de display list
            background = new BackgroundPicture();
            background.width = 1240;
            background.height = 800;
            addChild(background);

            // Toevoeging van het de vogel op de display list
            calimeroDeVogel = new Vogel();
            calimeroDeVogel.scaleX = 1;
            calimeroDeVogel.scaleY = 1;
            calimeroDeVogel.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            addChild(calimeroDeVogel);

            // Toevoeging van de zon op de display list
            movingSun = new Sun();
            movingSun.scaleX = 1;
            movingSun.scaleY = 1;
            movingSun.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            addChild(movingSun);

            // Toevoeging van de muur op de display list
            Gebouw = new Muur();
            Gebouw.scaleX = 1;
            Gebouw.scaleY = 1;
            Gebouw.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            addChild(Gebouw);


            // het gedeelte voor de muziek
            // maakt een request aan genaamd jesseSong die zoekt naar het aangegeven mp3 bestand        
            achtergrondMuziek = new Sound; 
            URLRequest("music/chirp.mp3");
            achtergrondMuziek.play();
            achtergrondMuziek.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

        }

        // event toevoegen
        public function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
            calimeroDeVogel.x+=4;}

            if (calimeroDeVogel.hitTestObject(Gebouw))
            {
                blam = new Blam
                blam.x = 200;
                addChild(blam)
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no `super()` in your constructor
2. `calimeroDeVogel.x+=4;}` - **}** wraps up the function; place it after your **if**